# Create a custom cell according to the type of data retrieved

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

my app has a TableView with a custom cell.
I would like to specify that use Parse.com

I wish my cell had an image according to the data type called ... for example:

If the query contains data that are waiting to be completed, the cell must have a picture "red image"

otherwise

If the query contains the data obtained completed the cell must have a "green image".

how could I do? I apologize if the explanation is difficult but the result I want is that the user of the app can determine what data are to be completed and which are not through the display of a Table View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Parse.com class - add a column `dataCompleted` with a `bool` value.

When processing your query results within `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (for `UITableView`) or `cellForItemAtIndexPath` (for `UICollectionView`), check the bool value for the `dataCompleted` key and set the image accordingly.

```
// _dataSource is an array of PFObjects from the Parse.com query
PFObject *rowObject = [_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if([[rowObject objectForKey:@"dataCompleted"] boolValue])
{
    // Data is completed
    cell.outletDataCompletedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_dataiscompleted"];
}
else
{
    // Data still to be completed
    cell.outletDataCompletedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_datastilltobecompleted"];
}
```

Comment: Great Phil! thanks a lot!! I understood perfectly what you meant!
Take advantage of your kindness: D

I also have another Tableview always with data from parse.com where I placed a order with queryfortable descend according to the "Date" selected by a pickerdate. Now the earliest date turns out to be the last cell and only in the last cell I would like to add a picture ... In this specific case, how could I do? This is more 'complicated for me: (

thanks Rory

Comment: That's a separate question to this one. Mark this answer as accepted and create a new question.

Comment: Thanks Phil, i added another question :) thank you so much  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196590/ad-image-only-last-cell-in-tableviewcontroller