# Ad Image only last Cell in TableViewController

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform

I have a TableView with data from parse.com where I Placed order to descend according to Functional queryfortable with the "Date" selected by a pickerdate. Now the earliest date turns out to be the last cell and only in the last cell I would like to add a image ... In this specific case, how could I do? This is more 'complicated for me: (

I need to insert an image only in the last cell

Thanks Rory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `PFQueryTableViewController` then you should be using a custom subclass of it.

```
/// MyPFQueryTableViewController.h
@interface MyPFQueryTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController
```

`self.objects` is the Datasource array the PFQueryTableViewController class uses for each table row.

You have to check whether the `indexPath.row` is the last object inside the `self.objects` array.

Within `MyPFQueryTableViewController.m` you override the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    // Is this the last displaying cell?
    if( indexPath.row == ([self.objects count]-1) )
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"End_Of_List.jpg"];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:self.textKey];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Phil Thank you very much you have been very kind to help me ... I hope I can reciprocate in some way when you serve! :) Thank you so much!